# One field in database row will not delete

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently creating a website that links to a backend database, I have an account page that can be updated by the user. I have been trying to include a button that allows the currently logged in user to delete their account.

At the minute all the fields are deleted except for the username which means login is still an option.

Does anyone have a way around this. Please note that I am using sessions.

```
<?php

    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","labuser","Labuser1");

    $DB = mysql_select_db('ubiquiblog');
    $query = "DELETE * FROM user_details WHERE username = '$username'";

    if (!mysql_query($query, $connect))
        die("ERROR : Unable to query db : " . mysql_error());

?>
```

[image: screenshot]

Problem With redirect on frontend page

Thanks for your help everyone :)

_______________________________CLOSED_________________________________________

Comment: Can you paste the code used to delete the record? As it is very hard to see whats wrong from your basic description.

Comment: For starters, you don't delete fields. A `DELETE` statement deletes entire rows. Another problem I see is that you're `die`-ing with an error message when the call to `mysql_query()` is successful

Comment: @ Phil I think the poster is trying to delete the whole row.

Comment: Have fixed that error still have the same problem. The username stored on the session will not delete from the row. The rest of the row will delete but the username wont.

Comment: Try using just: mysql_query($query, $connect); without the die to see if that solves the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by `The rest of the row will delete`? Can you provide a screenshot of a db table row?

Comment: What does `echo $query` print on the screen? Is there an error message after you execute the query?

Comment: Are you sure the username is not being added again somehow after the delete?

Comment: no error message just refreshes the screen and deletes most of the row

Comment: @l_t no because it is added in a query with all the other details so if it was being re added so would all the other fields

Comment: Hmm... very strange indeed! At the top of your PHPMyAdmin window, with your database selected, choose SQL and run this query: `DELETE FROM user_details WHERE username = 'peter';` - does it work as it's supposed to? The reason I'm asking you to do this is because this way, you're doing the query *directly* on the database. No PHP involved to mess things up...

Comment: @Danny you know PHPMyAdmin is written in PHP, right ;)

Comment: One more (unrelated) thing, too: don't store passwords in plain-text. Use a hashing algorithm like SHA1, combined with a salt. When logging in, compare the hashes.

Comment: @Phil Of course... but I trust the PHPMyAdmin guys to not write weird PHP that does stuff like this ;) ...i.e. by not involving the OP's logic, this will probably work. Meaning that the problem is that the row gets reinserted after being deleted. If it doesn't work, I'll eat my proverbial hat.

Comment: yeah @DannyBeckett it works in the database. This is not a live site and probably wont be so i havent used any encrption or hashing

Answer (score 1):

First, you should not be using the MySQL extension. It has been deprecated. You should be using PDO or MySQLi. I recommend the former.

Here's an example of a simple delete statement

```
<?php
session_start(); // you'll need this to access anything in $_SESSION

// enable error reporting for development
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    throw new Exception('No username in session');
}

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ubiquiblog;charset=utf8',
    'labuser', 'Labuser1');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM `user_details` WHERE `username` = ?');
$stmt->bindParam(1, $_SESSION['username']);

$stmt->execute();

printf('Deleted %d row(s) for username "%s"',
    $stmt->rowCount(), $_SESSION['username']);
```

Comment: thanks but still same issue

Comment: @SeaninLedgewood I've just updated my answer. I'd say the real problem here was that you are missing the call to `session_start()`

Comment: Thanks but same again im afraid :(

Comment: @SeaninLedgewood I've updated my answer again with some better debugging options. You should at least see some errors if things go wrong

Comment: no errors or anything just refreshes the screen and stops there.

Comment: @SeaninLedgewood Do you see the *"Deleted 1 rows..."* message?

Comment: No it doesnt display anything

Comment: @SeaninLedgewood In that case, I must assume you're not using the code in my answer at all or there's more code you're adding to it that you have not shown

Comment: no i copy and pasted it into the back end file

Comment: i understand whats happening now the redirect to the backend file wasnt happening correctly.

Comment: @SeaninLedgewood What redirect? My answer contains no such thing

Comment: yeah it was a mistake on my behalf, i worked it out